# Image does not move to the right

Tags: html, css

My Umali image won't move to the right side. Does anyone know what is wrong with it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url('../Images/dessertblack.png');
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.coatofarms {
  width: 5%;
  z-index: 15;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5%;
  top: -1%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e1bc85;
  position: absolute;
  top: %;
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: Bodoni Mt;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #98856f;
  color: white;
}

table {
  background-color: #98856f;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.5%;
  top: 6.5%;
}

.buttonimage {
  opacity: 0.9;
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 81%;
  left: 42.5%;
}

.buttonimage:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.liver {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 23%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fatta {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38%;
  top: 26.7%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
}


}
.umali {}
.ltext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 5.9%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Algerian;
}
.ftext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 41.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Algerian;
}
.utext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 80.5%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Algerian;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Food</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/flag.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/food.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="file:///D:/Egypt%20Website/index.html">
    <div class="coatofarms"><img src="Images/coabetter.png" class="coa" width="75px" z-index="2"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#food">Food</a>
    <a href="#placestogo">Landmarks</a>
    <a href="#visit">Visit Us</a>

  </div>

  <!--liver-->
  <img src="Images/box.png" alt="liver alexandria style" class="liver">
  <p class="ltext">
    This is Liver Alexandria<br> Style, It is a main<br> dish in Egyptian cuisene.<br> It is usually mixed with<br> hot spices and lemons.<br> The Liver has a different<br> taste from other meats<br> so the spices help. </p>

  <!--fatta-->
  <img src="Images/boxbig.png" alt="fatta" class="fatta">
  <p class="ftext">
    This is called fatta. It is generaly<br> Made of rice, meat and pita bread.<br> It is sometimes topped a sauce and<br> Some vegetables. It is a original<br> Dish ancient egypt that is still<br> Eaten today.</p>

  <!--Umali-->
  <img src="Images/umalibox.png" alt="umali" class="umali">
  <p class="utext">
    This is called Um Ali,it is<br> a Egyptian desert. It is a<br> type of bread putting. It<br> usually has raisins<br> inside of it.</p>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Your `.umali` class is completely empty so unless you forgot to paste that into your post, that's probably why it's not doing anything. You also have an extra `}` at the end of your `.fatta` class that you can get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Your umali class was empty.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url('../Images/dessertblack.png') ;
   width:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.coatofarms {
    width: 5%;
    z-index: 15;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5%;
    top: -1%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e1bc85;
  position:absolute;
  top: %;
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: Bodoni Mt;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #98856f;
  color: white;
}




table {
    background-color:#98856f;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.5%;
    top: 6.5%;
}

.buttonimage {
opacity: 0.9;
width: 15%;
position: absolute; 
top: 81%;
left: 42.5%;
}

.buttonimage:hover {
opacity: 0.8;
}

.liver {
    position:absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 26.7%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.fatta {
    position:absolute;
    left: 38%;
    top:26.7%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    pointer-events: none; 
}

.umali {
    position:absolute;
    left: 78%;
    top:26.7%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    pointer-events: none;    
}


.ltext {
    position: absolute;
    top:60%;
    left: 5.9%;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Algerian;
    
}


.ftext {
    position: absolute;
    top:60%;
    left: 41.5%;
    z-index: 1; 
    font-family: Algerian;
}

.utext {
    position: absolute;
    top:60%;
    left: 80.5%;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: Algerian;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <a href="file:///D:/Egypt%20Website/index.html"><div class="coatofarms"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/green" class="coa" width="75px" z-index="2"></div></a>
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#food">Food</a>
  <a href="#placestogo">Landmarks</a>
  <a href="#visit">Visit Us</a>
  
</div>

<!--liver-->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="liver alexandria style" class="liver"> <p class="ltext">
This is Liver Alexandria<br>
Style, It is a main<br>
dish in Egyptian cuisene.<br>
It is usually mixed with<br>
hot spices and lemons.<br>
The Liver has a different<br>
taste from other meats<br>
so the spices help. </p>

<!--fatta-->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="fatta" class="fatta"> <p class="ftext">
This is called fatta. It is generaly<br>
Made of rice, meat and pita bread.<br>
It is sometimes topped a sauce and<br>
Some vegetables. It is a original<br>
Dish ancient egypt that is still<br>
Eaten today.</p>

<!--Umali-->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="umali" class="umali"> <p class="utext">
This is called Um Ali,it is<br>
a Egyptian desert. It is a<br>
type of bread putting. It<br>
usually has raisins<br>
inside of it.</p>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```